# Use 7z On Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, 7-zip

I can... but should I?

I run 2 ubuntu 20.04 servers and an ubuntu 20.04 desktop.  I have been using 7zip on my desktop to save space on large tars that I move to long-term storage.

I have cputool installed on all machines and I use the following 7z command to get (ultra) small archive sizes.

`cputool --load-limit 7.5 --cpu-limit 40 --  nice -n 19 7za -v17g a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe -pXXXX Directory.tar.7z Directory.tar`

While the above command satisfies my needs on a laptop with 19GB of RAM and 4GB swap, it however comes with a significant memory hit while it executes.

**Question:**
My servers are currently running with 2 cpu, 4GB of Ram and 4GB swap... Does anyone know how I can limit 7zip's memory usage when it executes?

Might something like this work?
`systemd-run --scope uid=100 -p MemoryHigh=500mb 7z-wrapper-script.sh`

Comment: I would consider the cost of extra space vs the chances of losing huge quantities of data if a compressed file is damaged. Drives are cheap.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have expansion plans, I am building a webhosting comany.  Whether `tar.7z` or `tar.gz`  there is always a chance of disk corruption causing archive corruption.. So, I would rather save on bandwith by downloading smaller backup files, quicker.    The question is how can limit the CPU usage, so that backups don't interfere with the rest of the server.

Comment: Are you asking about memory usage or CPU usage? Because you can lower CPU usage at the cost of time, but there's no way to lower memory usage without changing algorithms or their parameters. Compression uses as much memory as it needs, no more, no less.

Comment: @gronostaj  I am specifically asking about memory...  I can easily limit the CPU in the command above.  If I starve it of CPU will that lower my memory impact... or am I just extending the time period of high memory usage?

Comment: You're just extending the time period of high memory usage. Some apps will adjust memory usage to the current situation, but compression is not one of these workloads. You have to tweak the parameters or change the algorithm (eg. give zstd a try).

Comment: Rather than store the data compressed, companies such as Backblaze will compress on the fly for any data restore you need from them. Backup safety is therefore not compromised by putting all eggs in one basket. The compressed archive is kept for maybe a week before the space is freed up again.

Comment: @gronostaj  see above... what do you think?

Comment: The memory requirements of 7z are a direct result of the parameters used. Want 7z to use less memory? Use different parameters. If 7z cannot allocate the memory it requires, it will most likely crash.

Comment: @DanielB fair enough... took a shot.. :-/